# How to keep mocked values in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have these two codes:

```
jest.mock('hooks/limitIncrease', () => ({
  limitIncrease: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    setReason: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

And in the same file, but in isolated test case, i have:

```
  (limitIncrease as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce({
        handleSubmitNewLimit: handleSubmitNewLimitMock,
      });
```

And in this isolated teste case, it return

`TypeError: setReason is not a function`

How do i keep the mocked values? I known a solution, but it's not a better option (i believe).

My solution:

```
const mockedData = {
  setReason: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock('hooks/limitIncrease', () => ({
  limitIncrease: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockedData),
}));
```

```
 (limitIncrease as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce({
...mockedData,
        handleSubmitNewLimit: handleSubmitNewLimitMock,
      });
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense. When you mock return value or implementation, you replace it completely. There is no "merge this object with properties of previous implementation", you have to do it yourself like you did.

Comment: Amazing @juraj ! I thought it was possible to do it another way.. Very thanks, dude